# No module named java.lang.System when run Python in UNIX

Tags: java, python, unix

I'm new to Python and I have a Python script now, when I try to run it in UNIX: 
python execute.py, it throws out an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "execute.py", line 7, in <module>
import java.lang.System
ImportError: No module named java.lang.System
```

And below is the beginning of the Python script:

```
#ident    "%W%"
import os
import sys
sys.path.append('/opt/jdk/1.8.0_91l64/bin')
print sys.path
#import java.net.InetAddress
import java.lang.System
```

So may I know how to import Java modules in Python?

Comment: This sounds like a troll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do is only possible in the [Jython](http://www.jython.org/) interpreter -- which is essentially a dead project. (It has not been updated since 2015, and appears unlikely to ever support Python3.)

In practical terms: if you want to use Java packages, use Java. If you want to write Python, you'll need to use use Python modules for the functionality you want.

Comment: yeah, this script is from an old project, I might need to rewrite it to Java.